# How to retrieve data from the myphpadmin server based on the current date?

Tags: php, mysql

I need help creating php code that will pull an image saved within the root folder based on the current date. In other words, each day a new image will be displayed on the webpage when the next day occurs. Below is the table.

```
date                                file_location   
Wednesday, Jan 02, 2013 12:00 AM    "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-01.png"    
Thursday, Jan 03, 2013 12:00 AM     "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-02.png"    
Friday, Jan 04, 2013 12:00 AM       "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-03.png"    
Saturday, Jan 05, 2013 12:00 AM     "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-04.png"    
Sunday, Jan 06, 2013 12:00 AM       "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-05.png"    
Monday, Jan 07, 2013 12:00 AM       "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-06.png"    
Tuesday, Jan 08, 2013 12:00 AM      "...\journal_prompts\2013-01-07.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use databases for this? You can easily do it, only using PHP:

```
<img src="...\journal_prompts\
    <?php echo(strftime("%Y-%m-%d")); ?>
.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this--

```
<?php
$img = date('Y-m-d').".png";
?>
<img  src="...\journal_prompts\<?php echo $img?>" alt="today pic"/>
```

Comment: Guys, this worked! Thanks for your help!

"<?php
$img = "images/prompts/".date('Y-m-d').".png";
?>

<img  src="<?php echo $img?>" alt="today pic" alt="Today's Prompt"/>"